# Can I throw sqlalchemy.exc error in Flask by Flask error handler?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, sqlalchemy

I was getting sqlalchemy.exc.timeouterror for queuepool  limit size reached, but then I changed it from default to 100  and also tried @app.teardown_request and method but now I am getting sqlalchemy.exc.operational error. If these method doesn't work Can I just catch sqlalchemy error by default error handler, or is there any other way to work properly?

my config code:

```
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"]=False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"]="filesystem"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] =False
app.config['FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH'] = 'cerulean'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE']=100
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW']=15
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT']=30
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE']=1000
```

My signup and signin function that uses database connection:

```
@app.route("/signup",methods=["POST","GET"])
def signup():
    if request.method=="POST":
        first_name=request.form.get("first_name")
        last_name=request.form.get("last_name")
        email=request.form.get("email")
        gender=request.form.get("gender")
        birthday=request.form.get("birthday")
        password=request.form.get("password")
        password2=request.form.get("password2")
        hashed=pbkdf2_sha256.hash(password)
        if User.query.filter_by(email=email).first():
            flash(u"Email already exists","danger")
            return redirect(url_for('signup'))
        if password!=password2:
            flash(u"Both password should be same","warning")
            return redirect(url_for('signup'))
        if not validate_email(email):
            flash(u"Email not valid","error")
            return redirect(url_for('signup'))
        try:
            user=User(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,email=email,gender=gender,birthday=birthday,hash=hashed)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
        except TimeoutError:
            db.session.rollback()
            return render_template('500.html')
        finally:
            db.session.close()
        flash(u"You have registered successfully","success")
        return redirect(url_for('signin'))
    return render_template("signup.html")
@app.route("/signin",methods=["POST","GET"])
def signin():
    if request.method=="POST":
        email=request.form.get("email")
        password=request.form.get("password")
        user=User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if current_user.is_active:
            flash(u"You are already logged in","warning")
            return redirect(url_for('signin'))
        if not user:
            flash(u'User not found','error')
            return redirect(url_for('signin'))
        if not pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password,user.hash):
            flash(u"Incorrect password","danger")
            return redirect(url_for('signin'))
        login_user(user)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template("signin.html")
@app.route("/calender",methods=["POST","GET"])
```

My flask internal sever error handler:

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    return render_template('500.html'), 500
```

and finally teardown_request function that I get from another answer:

```
@app.teardown_request
def checkin_db(exc):
    try:
        db.session.remove()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

I am using postgresql that is running on heroku.

Comment: So your question is whether you can catch `sqlalchemy.exc.operational` for your view functions?

Comment: Yes, or there any other way I can resolve without catching these sqlalchemy error

Comment: I have also tried something like , from sqlalchemy.exc import TimeoutError and then pass it as error handler argument but failed.